# Zookeeper & Kafka - Error Invalid config, exiting abnormally

Tags: ubuntu, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I tried to run [ZooKeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/) in [Apache Kafka](https://ubuntu.com/managed/apps/kafka) ubuntu and i got this error:

[image: error i got for zookeeper]

also kafka process terminated with this error

```
022-02-23 01:08:23,690] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-02-23 01:08:23,709] INFO App info kafka.server for 0 unregistered  (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)


[2022-02-23 01:08:23,710] INFO shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2022-02-23 01:08:23,711] ERROR Exiting Kafka. (kafka.Kafka$)
[2022-02-23 01:08:23,725] INFO shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `sudo`
2. `-daemon` is only needed with the `server-start` scripts.
3. You need to change directories to the location where either `bin` or `config` folders exist, or use *absolute paths* for both.
4. `.properties.sh` is not a valid file extension for any files unless you've renamed them
5. You should really add `$KAFKA_HOME/bin` folder to your `PATH`... The location of the properties file doesn't matter as long as you give an absolute path.

Overall, I suggest following the APT installation instructions from Confluent Platform or use `brew`, and use `systemctl`  or `brew services` to start/stop Kafka and Zookeeper.

Comment: i already add the path of kafka/bin in the "/etc/environment" and try the following command 
"bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties"
in this path "/usr/local/kafka/bin"

Comment: I suggest you use `~/.bashrc`, not anything in `/etc` to edit your `PATH`

Comment: After correctly setting your PATH, you don't need to use `bin/` prefix anymore. You can just run `zookeeper-server-start /full/path/to/zookeeper.properties`